# Testing Undefined Behavior

Tags: c++, testing, undefined-behavior

Is it possible, within the confines of only the C++ language, to write a test that isolates and detects undefined behavior when executed? For example, given the following code:

```
void fn(int* p) {
  int x = *p;
}

void foo() {
  int x = 42;
  fn(&x);
}

void bar() {
  fn(nullptr);
}
```

Is it possible to construct a test that invokes `foo` and `bar`, and "passes" for `foo` but "fails" for `bar`?  My assumption is that ***it is not possible*** because the very act of invoking `bar` means the compiler is free to generate code that always passes, always fails, only fails on Tuesdays, or just prints "thanks for all the fish" in an endless loop. Still I'd like to get confirmation from the experts that this is the case.

Note: I'm aware of things like clang's ubsan, static analysis tools, and platform-specific traps to assist with detection of UB, but my question is limited to the C++ language only.

Comment: It's conceptually impossible to detect undefined behavior after the fact. Even detecting conditions that will produce UB *before* the fact is not reliable, unless detecting it also provides the possibility to avoid it in some ways. So detecting that `p` will be `nullptr` isn't enough if you actually then call `fn(nullptr)`.

Comment: Undefined behavior is called that way for a reason - the behavior is undefined, anything can happen. You can't test for it, because program logic will not follow the logic defined by C++ abstract machine.

Comment: A memory sanitized can detect most of them, so I'd run my tests using one or using valgrind

Comment: Do you know that the program can potentially summon nasal demons when facing undefined behavior? How do you detect them with C++ code?

Answer (score 6):

*Undefined behavior* is defined as a [behavior for which the C++ Standard imposes no requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.undefined). This basically means that the *defined behavior* is imposed by the requirements from the Standard.

You can never tell whether some behavior is defined or undefined just by observing that behavior (in both cases, the observable behavior may be the very same). You may only want to check whether all the requirements from the Standard have been met. However, such check is generally infeasible.

---

Consider your simple example. You can check `p` for null pointer, but, if it's not null, there is no way to tell whether it actually does or does not point to a valid object of type `int`. It might be possible in your simple program, provided it's compiled as a standalone translation unit, but generally it is not.

Comment: There are some cases where the C++ Standard imposes requirements upon the processing of "Undefined Behavior".  For example, if one template expansion would cause certain kinds of "Undefined Behavior" and another would not, the Standard would require that compilers use the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is sound and it is indeed not possible to test for undefined behaviour within the confines of the C++ language.

Answer (score 1):

If the functions can be written as `constexpr`, and you're okay with the code *not compiling* if there is an error, you can catch quite a few cases. The compiler will often be friendly enough to tell you why. For example in your case, GCC says this:

> error: dereferencing a null pointer

The trick is that undefined behavior is not allowed in a constant expression. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/XnIrnX

```cpp
constexpr void fn(int* p) {
  int x = *p;
}

constexpr void foo() {
  int x = 42;
  fn(&x);
}

constexpr void bar() {
  fn(nullptr);
}

//No error here
static_assert([]() constexpr -> bool { foo(); return true; }());

//This line gets an error
static_assert([]() constexpr -> bool { bar(); return true; }());
```